# How do I drop a group if one value matches another in the same column, but after a specific point in time?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning, economics

I have a df containing employment information. I want to drop workers who were reemployed at the same firm, post-layoff. I can identify firms by the EmploymentOrganizationID variable and layoffs are indicated by the dummy PermSeparation variable (1 = layoff; 0 = no layoff). I also have a Time_To_Layoff variable, which indicates how many years away the worker is from their layoff.

Essentially, the coding criteria is:

- For each worker (PersonID), any EmploymentOrganizationID value after PermSeparation==1 cannot be the same as before PermSeparation==1

I tried the following, but I'm getting an "unexpected >" error

```
df %>%
  group_by(PersonID) %>%
  mutate(EmpID = ifelse(Time_To_Layoff < 1 & EmploymentOrganizationID != Time_To_Layoff >0 EmploymentOrganizationID))
```

Here are the first 500 rows of the df:

```
structure(list(PersonID = c(185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 
185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 278, 278, 278, 
278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 
278, 278, 278, 1360, 1360, 1360, 1360, 1360, 1360, 1360, 1360, 
1360, 1360, 1360, 1360, 1360, 1360, 1360, 1360, 1360, 1360, 1534, 
1534, 1534, 1534, 1534, 1534, 1534, 1534, 1534, 1534, 1534, 1534, 
1534, 3136, 3136, 3136, 3136, 3136, 3136, 3136, 3136, 3136, 3136, 
3136, 3136, 3136, 3136, 3136, 3136, 3136, 3136, 3234, 3234, 3234, 
3234, 3234, 3234, 3234, 3234, 3234, 3234, 3234, 3234, 3234, 3234, 
3234, 3234, 3234, 3234, 3234, 3345, 3345, 3345, 3345, 3345, 3345, 
3345, 3345, 3345, 3345, 3345, 3345, 3486, 3486, 3486, 3486, 3486, 
3486, 3486, 3486, 3486, 3486, 3486, 3486, 3486, 3486, 3486, 3486, 
3486, 3486, 3486, 3743, 3743, 3743, 3743, 3743, 3743, 3743, 3743, 
3743, 3743, 3743, 3743, 3743, 4166, 4166, 4166, 4166, 4166, 4166, 
4166, 4166, 4166, 4166, 4166, 4166, 4166, 4889, 4889, 4889, 4889, 
4889, 4889, 4889, 4889, 4889, 4889, 4889, 4889, 4889, 4889, 4889, 
4889, 4889, 4889, 4889, 4910, 4910, 4910, 4910, 4910, 4910, 4910, 
4910, 4910, 4910, 4910, 4910, 4910, 4910, 4910, 4910, 4910, 4910, 
5062, 5062, 5062, 5062, 5062, 5062, 5062, 5062, 5062, 5062, 5062, 
5062, 5062, 5062, 5062, 5062, 5062, 5062, 5062, 5209, 5209, 5209, 
5209, 5209, 5209, 5209, 5209, 5209, 5209, 5209, 5209, 5209, 5209, 
5514, 5514, 5514, 5514, 5514, 5514, 5514, 5514, 5514, 5514, 5514, 
5904, 5904, 5904, 5904, 5904, 5904, 6306, 6306, 6306, 6306, 6306, 
6306, 6306, 6306, 6306, 6477, 6477, 6477, 6477, 6477, 6477, 6477, 
6477, 6477, 6477, 6477, 6477, 6477, 6477, 6477, 6477, 7255, 7255, 
7255, 7255, 7255, 7255, 7255, 7255, 7255, 7255, 7255, 7255, 7255, 
7255, 7255, 7255, 7255, 7255, 7255, 7645, 7645, 7645, 7645, 7645, 
7645, 7645, 7645, 7645, 7645, 7645, 7645, 7645, 8914, 8914, 8914, 
8914, 8914, 8914, 8914, 8914, 8914, 8914, 8914, 8914, 8914, 8914, 
8914, 8914, 8914, 8914, 8914, 8936, 8936, 8936, 8936, 8936, 8936, 
8936, 8936, 8936, 8936, 8936, 8936, 8936, 8936, 8936, 8936, 8936, 
8936, 8936, 9902, 9902, 9902, 9902, 9902, 9902, 9902, 9902, 9902, 
9902, 9902, 9902, 9902, 9902, 9902, 9902, 9902, 9902, 10905, 
10905, 10905, 10905, 10905, 10905, 10905, 10905, 10905, 10905, 
10905, 10905, 10905, 10905, 10905, 10905, 10905, 11498, 11498, 
11498, 11498, 11498, 11498, 11498, 11498, 11498, 11498, 11498, 
11498, 11498, 11498, 11498, 11498, 11498, 11498, 11498, 11500, 
11500, 11500, 11500, 11500, 11500, 11500, 11500, 11500, 11500, 
11500, 11500, 11500, 11500, 11500, 11500, 11500, 11500, 11500, 
13043, 13043, 13043, 13043, 13043, 13043, 13043, 13043, 13043, 
13043, 13043, 13043, 13043, 13043, 13043, 13043, 13043, 13043, 
13043, 13586, 13586, 13586, 13586, 13586, 13586, 13586, 13586, 
13586, 13586, 13586, 13606, 13606, 13606, 13606, 13606, 13606, 
13606, 13606, 13606, 13606, 13606, 13606, 13606, 13606, 13606, 
13606, 13606, 13606, 14083, 14083, 14083, 14083, 14083, 14083, 
14083, 14083, 14083, 14083, 14083, 14083, 14083, 14083, 14083, 
14083, 14083, 14083, 14083, 17188, 17188, 17188, 17188, 17188, 
17188, 17188, 17188, 17188, 17188, 17188, 17188, 17188, 17188, 
17188, 17188, 18300), Year = c(2003, 2004, 2005, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 
2021, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2003, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2019, 2020, 2021, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 
2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2003, 
2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2019, 2020, 2021, 2003, 2004, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2007, 2008, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2013, 2005, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 
2021, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 
2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
2006, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2003, 
2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 
2021, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2003
), PermSeparation = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Time_To_Layoff = c(-13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, 
-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, 
-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -7, -6, -5, -4, 
-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -9, -8, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, 
-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, 
-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -6, 
-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
-11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 
0, 1, 2, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -5, -4, -3, 
-2, -1, 0, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, -17, -16, -15, -9, 
-8, -7, -6, -5, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, 
-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, -6, -4, -3, -2, 
-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, 
-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, -15, -14, -13, -11, -10, 
-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -4, -3, -2, -1, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, -15, -14, -13, -12, 
-11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -15, 
-14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 
0, 1, 2, 3, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -15, 
-14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 
0, 1, 2, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 
2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, -5), EmploymentOrganizationID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 261867L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 59664L, NA, 129292L, NA, NA, 126423L, NA, NA, 
126423L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 120987L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 50414L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 76742L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 94444L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 227828L, 252214L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 179105L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 36370L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 181807L, NA, NA, 
202487L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 145703L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2911L, 2911L, 2911L, 2911L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 212697L, 212697L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1041L, 1041L, 1041L, 
1041L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 144094L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 108505L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 97651L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 113271L, NA, NA, NA, 113271L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 228632L, 76742L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 97177L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 230682L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 65295L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4790L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 113924L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 209655L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 322993L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 107582L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 75839L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
186626L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 101670L, 101670L, 101670L, NA, 
NA, 101670L, 101670L, 101670L, NA, NA, 298247L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 131175L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -500L), groups = structure(list(PersonID = c(185, 
278, 1360, 1534, 3136, 3234, 3345, 3486, 3743, 4166, 4889, 4910, 
5062, 5209, 5514, 5904, 6306, 6477, 7255, 7645, 8914, 8936, 9902, 
10905, 11498, 11500, 13043, 13586, 13606, 14083, 17188, 18300
), .rows = structure(list(1:17, 18:36, 37:54, 55:67, 68:85, 86:104, 
    105:116, 117:135, 136:148, 149:161, 162:180, 181:198, 199:217, 
    218:231, 232:242, 243:248, 249:257, 258:273, 274:292, 293:305, 
    306:324, 325:343, 344:361, 362:378, 379:397, 398:416, 417:435, 
    436:446, 447:464, 465:483, 484:499, 500L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -32L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: So the `PermSeparation` variable is for all EmploymentOrganizationIDs? It's odd to me that row doesn't have an organization. Would user ever have more than one PermSeparation=1 true?

Comment: Workers can have an employment organization for PermSeparation==0 (the above example just happens to have NAs). All workers should have just 1 PermSeparation==1.

Comment: Your sample data posted doesn't match the data in the image. What is the desired output for the `dput()` data? It helps to have a specific case so we have something to test with. There doesn't appear to be any records to drop in your example.

Comment: The desired output is that workers like PersonID #1 get dropped, since they worked at the same firm before and after their lay-off.

Comment: There's no person #1 in the data you posted in the `dput()`. The whole point of including sample data is so we have something to copy/paste into R to test with. In the data you provided there are person IDs with 185 and 278 and neither have values that match what you show in the image. Most of the EmploymentOrganizationID values are NA.

Comment: I apologize for generating any confusion. The screenshot of the spreadsheet is a toy df, with the intention of presenting the issue in the most clear way, without involving all of the other variables. I could paste a screenshot of the actual df if that helps.

Comment: It would be better to post the toy data in a `dput()` format since that's the problem you described. The image isn't really necessary at all; we can't program anything using that without re-typing all the data. It would best best to remove any columns not related to the specific question you are asking as well.

Comment: Sounds good. I edited the original post by removing the screenshot and only selecting the necessary columns of the actual df used in the analysis for the dput().

Comment: I don't anticipate that many workers were re-employed at the same firm, post-layoff. This is more of a check on my analytic sample construction.

Comment: Anna, `EmploymentOrganizationID != Time_To_Layoff >0 EmploymentOrganizationID` is a parsing error as well as logically confusing. When I see an error like that, I immediately do a "Find" on my code to find all instances of `>`, and searching to see which of them (if many) seems aberrant. In this case it is clearly a parsing problem. Side note: your data has a lot of `NA`, note that most comparisons with `NA` values will return `NA`, so the logic has some "holes" in it.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is my version.

##### Disclaimer:

This is by no means foolproof, for example duplicate entries would cause wrong results without warning.

##### Creating a test case

In the data you provided, there is not a single case of reemployment. Also, as others have stated, it does not contain a person #1.

So I created a fictional Person #1.

```r
PersonID Year PermSeparation Time_To_Layoff EmploymentOrganizationID
       1 2010              0             -1                        1
       1 2011              1              0                        1
       1 2012              0              1                        1
       1 2013              1              0                        1
       1 2014              0              1                        2
       1 2015              1              0                        2
```

Explanation:

They were layed off at company 1, but got reemployed at the same company afterwards. Buut, they got layed off again later on, and started working for company 2. Eventually, they got layed off there as well. I think this covers every possible scenario.

**Data**

```r
test_df <- data.frame(PersonID = 1, 
           Year = 2010:2015,
           PermSeparation = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
           Time_To_Layoff = c(-1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2),
           EmploymentOrganizationID = c(rep(1, 4), 2, 2))
```

##### Approach

This is a `dplyr` solution.

```r
test_df |> 
  filter(!is.na(EmploymentOrganizationID)) |>  # Optional NA Removal
  group_by(PersonID, EmploymentOrganizationID) |>
  arrange(PersonID, EmploymentOrganizationID, Year) |>
  mutate(
    lead = case_when(
      PermSeparation == 1 ~ lead(PermSeparation)),
    reemployment = case_when(
      0 %in% lead ~ TRUE,
      1 %in% lead ~ TRUE,  # unlikely case but for completeness
      .default = FALSE)) #|>
#  filter(reemployment == FALSE)  # Optional filtering for no reemployment
```

**Results** (omitting the unused column `Time_To_Layoff`)

```
PersonID  Year PermSeparation EmploymentOrganizationID  lead reemployment    
       1  2010              0                        1    NA TRUE        
       1  2011              1                        1     0 TRUE        
       1  2012              0                        1    NA TRUE        
       1  2013              1                        1    NA TRUE        
       1  2014              0                        2    NA FALSE       
       1  2015              1                        2    NA FALSE
```

**Explanation**:

Grouping by Person and Company collects the cases where a person worked for the same company. So that part is done.

Now we have to check for a layoff in each group. If there was no layoff at all, its not worth investigating any further.
But in case there was a layoff, it would be interesting to see if there is more data in that group *after* the layoff. This would mean that the person worked for the same company after they got laid off.

This relies on correct ordering by year, which is made sure using `arrange()`.

`lead` is a helper column that displays the next value of `PermSeparation`, but only in case that `PermSeparation == 1` in the current row, e.g. person was actually laid off. Otherwise `lead` will be `NA`, especially in case that the layoff was the last entry in that company for that person.

To mark not only a single row, but the whole group as a case of "reemployment", we create yet another column `reemployment`.
We make use of the `%in%` operator to extend a single value to the whole group.

Note that, with this approach, I do not know how to separate pre-layoff and post-layoff data in a reemployment case, but I am sure there is a way. The current status is all data at the same company is marked as reemployment.

Data of the same person at a different company will not be marked as a reemployment. If you want to drop the person altogether, you would have to remove the company grouping prior to creating the `reemployment` column.